# Помощь в написании бота на python

Tags: python, бот

хочу сделать бота, суть такова, есть полукруглая зона по ней скачет белая полоса вперёд-назад, также есть зелёная зона, необходимо чтобы при нахождении конца белой полосы в зелёной зоне прожимался пробел, пример описанного на скрине ниже.

[image: ![Скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I65I8.png)]

Есть небольшие наработки (не мои):

```
import cv2
import pyautogui
import numpy as np
import time

# задать зону, где необходимо искать зеленый цвет
x, y, w, h = (764, 994, 150, 150)  # пример координат и размеров зоны

# задать диапазон зеленого цвета в формате HSV
lower_green = (90, 130, 70)  # пример нижнего значения диапазона
upper_green = (95, 140, 80)  # пример верхнего значения диапазона

# задать минимальное количество зеленых пикселей, необходимых для нажатия пробела
min_pixels = 1  # пример минимального количества зеленых пикселей

# задать частоту сканирования изображения в секундах
scan_frequency = 0.1  # пример частоты сканирования в полсекунды

# бесконечный цикл сканирования
while True:
# захватить изображение с экрана
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()

# преобразовать изображение в массив numpy и перевести в формат HSV
image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

# выделить зону на изображении
roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# создать маску изображения, используя диапазон зеленого цвета
mask = cv2.inRange(roi, lower_green, upper_green)

# вычислить количество зеленых пикселей на маске
green_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(mask)

# если количество зеленых пикселей больше или равно минимальному,
# нажать клавишу "пробел"
if green_pixels >= min_pixels:
    pyautogui.press('space')

# задержка до следующего сканирования
time.sleep(scan_frequency)
```

Comment: осталось разобраться с каким ботом вам помощь нужна...